# Form value to global var

Tags: javascript

I want to save a form value to a global value so I can compare it to another value in another function. I get the value from a form text field in a html page under the id pw1 then it works and I used an alert to display the value and it worked correctly, but when I used an alert in another function it just showed a blank space.

```
Pw=document.getElementById("pw1").value;
```

When I display it in other functions it just shows nothing. I used an alert to show the value in the other function but it just displayed a black slot.

Comment: Need to see more code

Comment: If `pw1` refers to a password field and if you are going to use a global variable to transfer a password to another function, it will be a very bad approach from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in window object if it's available’`window.variable_name =document.getElementById("input_id").value›`

Comment: Its still displaying an empty box

Comment: When are you updating the variable. Do you have some event listener functions to update variable.